# Cannot Activate/Import Bootstrap into my Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, sass, rubygems

I am trying to import/activate bootstrap in my Ruby on Rails application. I have added the`@import "bootstrap-sprockets";` followed by
`@import "bootstrap";` lines to my application.css.scss file and saved it. I also added `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.1'` to my Gemfile. I then restarted my server. When I launch the app from my browser, it doesn't appear that the bootstrap sass/css was applied. I can tell because the font never changed and the bootstrap navbar I added don't look correct. I have  tried closing out my browser and starting over and trying to launch the link from a different browser, but it doesn't help. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you `bundle install`? Also, have you also included the bootstrap javascripts in the `application.js` file?

Comment: First did you do `bundle install`?, and Do you see linked bootstrapped stylesheet in your `<head></head>` tag by viewing source code from browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your gem file:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

Inside your console

```
bundle install
```

app > assets > stylesheets > application.css

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Finally, rename the file from `application.css` to `application.css.scss` and restart your server. (Don't forget to add the JavaScript too.)

Comment: Importing "bootstrap-sprockets"; seemed to do the trick. The first answer may have worked as well, but I updated the GemFile just to be on the safe side and then restarted WEBrick.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add bootstrap .css files in assets and same goes for .js files. It should work then without installing gems. It is the best option as you can update your files with new versions whenever you want.